# How to get deleted file after rebase in git

Tags: git, fetch, commit, rebase

I have commited some files and I was followed step by step how to do it
but when I rebase the commit I get one file  deleted , I don't know why
you can see here the step that I was followed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: File is not deleted, it looks like it is having some merge conflicts. You have to resolve them manually. Since you are unable to get 3-way merge window, you may go to that file and search for "<<HEAD" and resolve the conflict and add this file. And then resume the rebase operation "git rebase --continue".

Comment: thank you it helpful, but I recreate file UsersController.php because i didn't found it in my local then I rebase operation and problem was solved

Comment: @love please make your comment like an answer, I will check it like solution